# How to show data on a table

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to show some data from my database with wpdb class, i'm using WP_List_Table class too.

So i got this code:

```
$wunder_plans_data = array();

foreach ($wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'wunder_plans' ) as $row ){
    $data = array(
      'ID' => $row->plan_id,
      'plano' => $row->plan_name,
      'dias' => $row->plan_days,
      'valor' => 'R$ ' . number_format( $row->plan_price, 2 ,',','.' )
    );

    $wunder_plans_data[]=$data;
}
```

But i'm when i test, it appears like this:

[image: The table output]

How can i fix that?

thank you very much

Comment: Can you post some more code - it's pretty much impossible to help you at the moment. Have you coded the appropriate row/column methods for handling output? Are you `print_r`'ing somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong, just switch this:

```
  function column_default($item, $column_name){
    switch($column_name){
        case 'rating':
        case 'director':
            return $item[$column_name];
        default:
            return print_r($item,true); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
    }
}
```

To this:

```
function column_default($item, $column_name){
    switch($column_name){
        case 'id':
            return $item['plan_id'];
        case 'plano':
            return $item['plan_name'];
        case 'dias':
            return $item['plan_days'];
        case 'valor':
            return 'R$ ' . number_format($item['plan_price'], 2 ,',','.');
        default:
            return print_r($item,true); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
    }
}
```